# Create XML Element at NEW Line

Tags: php, xml, dom

i have a following xml file.

```
<question id="1">2011-01-07 23:59:38</question>
<question id="2">2011-01-08 0:01:44</question>
<question id="3"></question>
```

i am adding new question element. however it keeps adding it in here:

```
<question id="1">2011-01-07 23:59:38</question>
<question id="2">2011-01-08 0:01:44</question>
<question id="3"></question><question id="4"></question>
```

Rather than that, i want the new element to be added to a new line like this:

```
<question id="1">2011-01-07 23:59:38</question>
<question id="2">2011-01-08 0:01:44</question>
<question id="3"></question>
<question id="4"></question>
```

How can i achieve this?
Here is my adding new element part of my code:

```
$question2 = $xpath->query("/question[position()=last()]->value(0)");

$id2 = $question2->getAttribute('id');
$item2 = $dom->createElement("question");
$question2->parentNode->insertBefore($item2, $question2 ->nextSibling);
$item2->setAttribute('id', $row['idquestions']);
```

Thanks!

Comment: @user446141: Xpath **selects** nodes, it **doesn't serialize** them. Retagging and changing title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to first insert a new text object containing a newline, and then insert the new element object after that. Whitespace is significant in XML (though many/most *uses* of XML ignore it).

Comment: Thanks for the info, could you also tell me the functions to create a new text object?